# Do the IPs assigned by CloudFront Dedicated IP stay the same forever?

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

If you use CloudFront and choose the dedicated IP approach to support clients without SNI, do the IP addresses stay the same forever? I understand that AWS must allocate 30-40 IPs around the world that are just assigned to your CDN, but can these IP addresses change over time? Or do they stay the same forever?

And is there an easy way to get the complete list of these IPs?

Comment: What user-agents are you supporting that don't have SNI? Web browsers that don't are years out of support. https://caniuse.com/sni

Answer (score 1):

All AWS services, including CloudFront, use the distributed data center located in different locations around the world. The assigned IP addresses do not change.

I recommend that you look at the json file for a list of all of the CloudFront ip addresses;

https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json

See other: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html

Answer (score 0):

"CloudFront doesn't support assigning a static IP address to distributions. When a user requests content from CloudFront, DNS returns 4 IP addresses of the edge location with the lowest latency. This allows content to be delivered with the best possible performance"

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-distribution-static-ip/